# Trying To Fetch The Latest Reddit Post With The Reddit API

Tags: php, json, api, cron, reddit

I am attempting to scrape an url from reddit and post it on my blog every 30 minutes. This is my current solution:

1. I created a php file named 'newpost.php' that fetches content from the reddit's api and posts it to my blog. (Every time the page is loaded it fetches/posts the newest reddit post). Here is the code:

   ```
   $json = file_get_contents("https://www.reddit.com/r/all/new.json?limit=1");
   $obj = json_decode($json);
   $url = $obj->data->children[0]->data->url;
   // the rest posts this url to my blog
   ```
2. I then created a cron job that runs this code every 30 minutes

   ```
   wget --no-cache --spider http://mywebsite.com/blogposter/newpost.php
   ```

---

My problem is that when the cron job runs it's 2nd time (after 1 hour) it is posting the same url as the first time. This only happens with the cron job. When I manually refresh my page in a browser every couple of minutes it posts a different url every time.

I think something is getting cached, but I'm not sure what. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looking at that API URL the `modhash` property changes, are you saying that is always the same? There could be any a proxy/cache somewhere at the system/network level, What if you had `file_get_contents("https://www.reddit.com/r/all/new.json?limit=1&random=" . mt_rand());` as your content source?

Comment: Good idea. I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: Turns out that it didn't work. I'm still getting repeat posts

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is causing that, but you should be able to get around it by creating a script-type oauth application and authenticating in your script.