# Navigating JSON tree to data from Reddit API

Tags: javascript, json, api, reddit

I will try and keep this short. I am a current student and have been attempting to retrieve the top 5 posts from the front page of Reddit and display the title and URL on an HTML page. It is probably something really simple, but I can't get it to work. I want to pass the data to my Handlebars template from a single variable. I keep receiving an unhandled promise warning. Here is my code.

```
let url = 'https://www.reddit.com/.json?limit=5';
let settings = { method: "Get"};
let redditData = ""
fetch(url, settings)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        redditData = [
    {
    title: data.children.data.title,
    url: data.children.data.url_overriden_by_dest
    }
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data` object is structured differently than they way you've coded it. Here is how to extract the information you want from the first child:

```
let url = 'https://www.reddit.com/.json?limit=5';
let settings = { method: "Get"};
let redditData = ""
fetch(url, settings)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        redditData = [
    {
    title: data.data.children[0].data.title,
    url: data.data.children[0].data.url_overriden_by_dest
    }
    ];
});
```

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443924/trying-to-fetch-the-latest-reddit-post-with-the-reddit-api

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check some documentation on how the function `fetch` works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Also, check how promises work [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

That being said, you have to access the object properties, only when the Promise has finished retrieving the data. One way is using the `Promise.allSettled` function.

Please see the following snippet working, with a slightly different way of organizing it:

```js
const url = "https://www.reddit.com/.json?limit=5";
const promise = fetch(url).then(res => res.json());

function formatHandlebarsData(data) {
  const childrenObj = data.value.data.children;
  
  return childrenObj.map(element => ({
    title: element.data.title,
    url: element.data.url
  }));
}

Promise.allSettled([promise]).then(([data]) => {
  const handlebarsData = formatHandlebarsData(data);
  
  // You can use the object now
  console.log(handlebarsData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome. I was able to get it working with

```
let url = 'https://www.reddit.com/.json?limit=5';
let settings = { method: "Get"};
let redditData = ""
fetch(url, settings)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        redditData = [
    {
    title: data.data.children[0].data.title,
    url: data.data.children[0].data.url_overriden_by_dest
    }
    ];
});
```

Thanks!